# Automatic Replace "0" with blank cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a sheet called "Test". Column B shows dynamic API calls, then I use a macro to copy all cells from Column B to Column C every 1 hour in order to store those prices, however sometimes API call fails, so it shows 0. I want to mass replace all cells containing "0" (match exact case) from all columns of sheet "Test" **without changing** Column B (which is the column for the API calls so we don't want to change its formula).
How can I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue using something **you** have tried.   Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: Replace all cells with what?  Please provide examples.

Answer (score 0):

Google sheets doesn't have this function yet but this could do the trick:

1. Select all cells (Ctrl + A) click Format > Conditional Formatting
2. Use the dropdown to select Equal To and type 0
3. Tick the text tickbox and change the text color to white, this will
   effectively hide all your zero values.

Comment: Thank you but that's not what im looking for since the data are used to make charts, so even if they are not visible they will still be counted in charts.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a format as

```
0;-0;
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that my macro will create a new column and paste cells from Column B every 1 hour. So with your method I will have to manually adjust every new column, i was hoping for a more automated method. Thanks

Comment: you may be can define the format by script